# Google Consumer Surveys for Publisher not Working

Tags: javascript, adsense

I'm unable to get consumer surveys (for publishers) to appear on my site. I've followed the instructions to the letter.

Installed js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  var ARTICLE_URL = window.location.href;
  var CONTENT_ID = 'everything';
  document.write(
    '<scr'+'ipt '+
    'src="//survey.g.doubleclick.net/survey?site=PUBLISHERID'+
    '&amp;url='+encodeURIComponent(ARTICLE_URL)+
    (CONTENT_ID ? '&amp;cid='+encodeURIComponent(CONTENT_ID) : '')+
    '&amp;random='+(new Date).getTime()+
    '" type="text/javascript">'+'\x3C/scr'+'ipt>');
})();
</script>
```

And wrapped my content:

```
<div class="p402_premium">
  <!-- YOUR PREMIUM CONTENT HERE -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  try { _402_Show(); } catch(e) {}
</script>
```

Anyone successfully installed GCS for publishers on their site?

Comment: If you are unable to get this to work, have you looked into Survata? They offer a [similar product](http://survata.com/publisher-network).

Answer (score 0):

I have been successful installing GCS on my site.

Have you tried to swap out the PUBLISHERID with your own GCS Account ID? 
https://support.google.com/consumersurveys/answer/3333507?hl=en&ref_topic=2476646

Comment: yes, I'm using my own publisher ID in place of PUBLISHERID